# Android values for different densities

Tags: android

Why we can not have, for example   5dp in both - values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml and values/dimens.xml ? It gives me an error for duplicating resources.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific, post relevant contents of both files and explain clearly what the problem is.

Comment: It should be fine. Please post both of your files for more information and exact error that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to define the same value twice :)
the xxhdpi used just if you want to specify an attribute for those devices that has that density but for your app you should put the general values in the

```
dimens.xml
```

and if you have some values for these devices add it in the right dimens file put change the name :)